# What does it mean to "take perturbations", e.g. $\sigma \rightarrow \sigma + \delta \sigma$, and how can I extend this to complex numbers??

Tags: complex-analysis, derivatives, several-complex-variables

In [this paper](https://www.doi.org/10.1088/0957-0233/13/12/310) the author has an equation (30) which reads

$\int_\Omega \sigma |\nabla u|^2 dx + \sum_\ell \int_{e_\ell} z_\ell \left(\sigma \nabla u \cdot \hat{n} \right)^2 dS = \sum_\ell V_\ell I_\ell$.

Then the author "takes perturbations" $\sigma \rightarrow \sigma + \delta\sigma$, $u \rightarrow u+ \delta u$, and $V \rightarrow V + \delta V$, and from this gets

$
\int_\Omega \delta \sigma |\nabla u|^2 dx
+ 2 \int_\Omega \sigma \nabla u \cdot \nabla \delta u\ dx
+ 2 \sum_\ell \int_{e_\ell} z_\ell \left(\sigma \nabla u \cdot \hat{n} \right) \delta \left(\sigma \nabla u \cdot \hat{n} \right) \ dS = \sum_\ell I_\ell \delta V_\ell.$

I think the author took what Wikipedia calls the ["total differential"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Differential_of_a_function#Differentials_in_several_variables), and that the $\delta \sigma$, etc. are the "differentials" of the independent variables.

I would like to extend this to have $\sigma$, $V_\ell$, and $u$ be complex, but after a couple of tries, I can't figure out how to reproduce a complex version of the authors result. In this case, $\sigma: \Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and $u:\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^3 \rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ and $V_\ell$ is a complex scalar.

How does one correctly "take perturbations" (total differentials?) of complex things?